# Can dnf scan for missing or corrupted files in packages?

Tags: fedora, dnf

After removing a number of packages' directories, `dnf` still believes those packages are installed. Although we may have some idea, we are not sure exactly which packages are affected. Can `dnf` check all packages file integrity and automatically remove them?

Comment: If you know what packages they are, then just `dnf uninstall <packages>`.

Comment: »»removing a number of packages' directories«« : `dnf` wouldn't know about any {deleted  files and/or directories} . **dnf** gets information from the rpm data base only.

Answer (score 1):

N.B.:  I'm no expert and I hope you get a much better answer than this, but ...

You can use `rpm` to `--verify` the installed packages/files.  I.e., `rpm` can look to see what should have been installed for each package and check if everything is still in the right place (and a lot of other stuff - read the `rpm` man page).  If a lot of files have been removed, `rpm` should scream at you with loads of "missing" messages.

Here's a super hacky and ugly `bash` one-liner that will print the rpm package that has "verify" issues.  I wouldn't worry too much about modified file permissions, etc., since you are looking for packages with missing/corrupted files.

```bsh
for p in $(rpm -q -a); do ret=$(sudo rpm -V $p); if [[ $ret != "" ]]; then echo $p; echo $ret; fi; done
```

`sudo` is used because not all files are readable by typical users.

The more packages you have installed, the longer it will take.  Be prepared to wait.  You should be able to identify what you are looking for.